# Displaying Raw JSON in HTML With Special Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to display some raw JSON data in HTML, and some of this JSON data may contain HTML special characters (<, & etc.) that need to be displayed and not interpreted by the page as HTML.

I am inserting the data onto the page using javascript like so:

```
$(child).html(JSON.stringify(bigJSONObject, null, 4));
```

Check out this JSFiddle for an example using a couple of different wrappers to display the JSON data.  http://jsfiddle.net/4ae7u/

As you can see, each of the wrappers interpret the JSON data as HTML.  What is the best way to have Javascript escape the HTML entities so the full JSON data shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/4ae7u/1/

```
$(child).text(JSON.stringify(bigJSONObject, null, 4));
```

Comment: I'm positive this is a duplicate of some other question, but i'm having a difficult time finding it.

Comment: It might be, but I couldn't find anything related to this before posting.  Thanks!